# Why am I getting this attribute error "'list' object has no attribute 'username'"?

Tags: python

When I try update records I get this error :

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'username'

Part of the code that's wrong :

```py
users.username = username
```

app.py :

```
@app.route('/account', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def account():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        currentUser = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        fields = [username, password, email]
        if fields == ['', '', '']:
            print("Workimg")
            return render_template('accountinfo.html',avisator=True)
        currentUser.password = password
        currentUser.email = email
        db.session.commit()
        print("Working")
    return render_template('accountinfo.html', avisator=False)
```

Database:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    task = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
```

Does anyone know why this error is happening?

Comment: because `users` appears to be list. you probably want to iterate it `for user in users:` and then do `user.username` inside the loop. Or if you are sure you only have one user, you can do `users[0].username`

Comment: I tried doing that, but it doesnt work.
Here is my code(it includes the database and the for loop)https://imgur.com/a/bAWZf0d

Comment: "still doesn't work" is not something we can work with. You will need to update your question with the new code you tried and the traceback error you are getting

Comment: Sorry. I was trying to edit the question, but it wasn't letting me, so I was stuck on the   edit comment thing.

Comment: Ok inside the loop I see you are still doing `users.username` instead of `user.username`. (same for password, email, and for the session add and session commit)

Comment: ```UnmappedInstanceError
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.list' is not mapped
```

Comment: your code still uses `users.username` instead of `user.username`. If you modified your code, you must update your question with the new code and the new error. Don;t post comments

Comment: Oh Whoops. I forgot to change it. Ok, I changed it but I still get that error.

Comment: Ok, read my comments carefully, because your code has `db.session.add(users)` but in my comment I mention "same for password, email, and for the **session add** and **session commit**". You are not making the suggested changes to your code. Also you got an answer from @Serzhan suggesting you to not query the database for all users and instead instance a user with the desired data.

Comment: Yes. I read about it, but the thing is. I am not trying to add a new user, I am trying to update the user.

Comment: Also I made the suggested changes, but this time a got the error as
```TypeError: commit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```

Comment: Yeah, make sure you just write `db.session.commmit()` without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You're `POST`ing only a single user with each request, you don't need to query the whole database. Just update, say the `currentUser`, directly by finding him/her in the db:

```py
@app.route('/account', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def account():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        currentUser = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        fields = [username, password, email]
        if fields == ['', '', '']:
            print("Workimg")
            return render_template('accountinfo.html', users=users, avisator=True)
        currentUser.password = password
        currentUser.email = email
        db.session.commit()
        print("Working")
    return render_template('accountinfo.html', users=users, avisator=False)
```

PS: You should add a method for caching the user ID and using that in the query for `currentUser` above rather than username, unless the username never changes and isn't allowed to change.

PPS: Since `image_file` is not `nullable`, you might consider changing the `User` model to disregard it or force the user to upload an image with the form.

Comment: Yes, but isn't the goal to Update the user? Implementing a new user wouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Ah, well then let me update my answer!

Comment: Ok! Thank you though to! Because your answer helped me figure something else out!

Comment: Ok, after changing the code I get this error. I put the changed code on the question. The Error was. currentUser.password = password
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'password'

Comment: That probably means there is no user by that `username` in the database. You should have that particular user register as new or create a new user entry in the database manually. Consider catching such errors in your app and giving the user correct Error messages. Also consider using a TDD approach to your app development - in this case, this would fall in the Unit test category, but that is a different question.